# How to delete blog word from wordpress url?

Tags: site-url

I try to setting up wordpress to display my posts such as

```
http://www.domain.com/postname
```

but the default url is

```
http://www.domain.com/blog
```

When I try to use custom structure for urls such as `/%postname%/` , wordpress generate urls with `blog` word `http://www.domain.com/blog/%postname%/`.

I think that this changed in wordpress 5 version.

How can i delete blog word from url? Is this possible?

Comment: Is your WordPress install inside a `/blog` directory?

Comment: No. I install wordpress in root folder

Comment: It sounds like a plugin may be involved. Have you tried using a default theme and deactivating all your plugins?